# Show progress while one cmdlet is running

Tags: windows, powershell, progress-bar, powershell-4.0, powershell-cmdlet

I know about Write-Progress cmdlet and use it.
This cmdlet is usefull where you want to show progress of an loop running for example, or when stack of cmdlets is running.

But how can  I show progress of a single cmdlet?
For example I run `Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited` for organization with about 10.000 mailboxes. Usually this take pretty lot of time and I wish if there was some progress bar, letting us know about progrees.

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How can i use Write-Progress in a Pipeline Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17605364/1701026)

Answer (score 1):

> But how can I show progress of a single cmdlet?

If the given cmdlet itself doesn't support displaying its progress, only *suboptimal* solutions are possible, as you'll have no insight into the internal state of the cmdlet as it is executing:

- If the cmdlet call either produces *no output* or you do not know *how many* output objects to expect, a simple solution is to **abstract *please-wait* progress display**, that you start showing just before your cmdlet call and hide when the call returns.

  - While suboptimal in terms of user feedback, this approach has the advantage of *not slowing down your call* with repeated progress-update operations; e.g.:

    ```
    Write-Progress 'Please wait' -Status '...'
    Start-Sleep 3 # Simulate a long-running command.
    Write-Progress -Complete '(unused)'
    ```
- If your cmdlet call *does* produce output objects and you want to **provide a progress update every time an output object / a fixed count of output objects is received**, you need to process each output object via [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) and make repeated [`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress) calls. This **invariably *slows down the operation***. **To mitigate** this overhead, **call `Write-Progress` only *after every N objects***, such as `5` in this example:

  ```
  # Specify after how many (additional) output objects to update the
  # progress display, so as not to spend too much time on updating.
  $updateEveryN = 5 

  Write-Progress -Activity 'Procressing' -Status '0 object(s) received...'

  # Simulate a long-running command
  $countReceived = 0
  1..21 | ForEach-Object { Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 200; $_ } |
    ForEach-Object {
      # Every N objects, update the count of objects received so far 
      if (0 -eq ++$countReceived % $updateEveryN) {
        Write-Progress -Activity 'Processing' -Status ('{0} object(s) received...' -f $countReceived)
      }
      $_ # Pass the output object through.
    }

  Write-Progress -Complete '(unused)'
  ```
- A ***percent-complete* display** is **only possible *if you happen to know how many output objects to expect*** (the caveat re slowing down your operation equally applies):

  ```
  # The total count of expected output objects.
  $totalCount = 22

  # Specify after how many (additional) output objects to update the
  # progress display, so as not to spend too much time on updating.
  $updateEveryN = 5 

  Write-Progress -Activity 'Procressing' -PercentComplete 0 -Status '0% complete'

  # Simulate a long-running command
  $countReceived = 0
  1..21 | ForEach-Object { Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 200; $_ } |
    ForEach-Object {
      # Every N objects, update the count of objects received so far 
      if (0 -eq ++$countReceived % $updateEveryN) {
        $percent = [Math]::Floor($countReceived / $totalCount * 100)
        Write-Progress -Activity 'Processing' -PercentComplete $percent -Status "$percent% complete"
      }
      $_ # Pass the output object through.
    }

  Write-Progress -Complete '(unused)'
  ```

Comment: thanks for such a comprehensive answer. But unfortunately everything is as I think.